# Calculating hypergeometric probability with approximations

Tags: r, probability, hypergeometric-distribution

I'm essentially trying to reproduce the `dhyper` function in R using
`!n ~ gamma(n+1)`. Why does this approach not work for large values of the population?

```
# (n choose k)
fastChoose <- function(parm_n, parm_k) {
   p1 = lgamma(parm_n+1)
   p2 = lgamma(parm_n - parm_k +1)
   p3 = lgamma(parm_k + 1)
   result = p1 - p2 - p3
   return (exp(result))
}

# P(X=k) = (K choose k) * (N-K choose K-k) / (N choose n)
myDHyper <- function(parm_k, parm_K, parm_N, parm_n){
   return (fastChoose(parm_K,parm_k) * fastChoose(parm_N-parm_K,parm_K - parm_k) /     fastChoose(parm_N,parm_n)) 
}

BIGN<-15000
whiteBallsInPop <- 50
iSampled<- 200
allPointMass<-c()
allPointMassMine <- c()
for(i in seq(0,whiteBallsInPop)){

  fromDHyper <- dhyper(i, whiteBallsInPop, BIGN-whiteBallsInPop, iSampled, log = FALSE)
  allPointMass <- c(allPointMass, fromDHyper)

  fromMyDHyper <- myDHyper(i,whiteBallsInPop,BIGN,iSampled)
  allPointMassMine <- c(allPointMassMine,fromMyDHyper )

} 

sum(allPointMass)
sum(allPointMassMine)
```

Keeping everything on log scale and taking log(p) doesn't seem to work either:

```
#log( P(X=x))
myDHyperOverflowFixed <- function(k, K, N, n){
  # P(X=k) = (K choose k) * (N-K choose K-k) / (N choose n)
  #        = K!/k!(K-k)! * (N-K)!/(K-k)!(N-K-K+k)! /  N!/n!(N-n)!

   log_p <- lgamma(K + 1) +
        lgamma(N - K + 1) +
        lgamma(n + 1) +
        lgamma(N - n + 1) - 
        lgamma(k + 1) - 
         lgamma(K - k + 1) - 
         lgamma(K - k + 1) - 
         lgamma(N - K - K + k + 1) -
         lgamma(N + 1)

 return (log_p)
}
```

Comment: Your new code *multiplies* $\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{K-k}$ by $\binom{N}{n}$ rather than dividing by it.

Comment: I don't think this is true.

Comment: You're right; I missed some minus signs. You can make your code much easier to check, though, by structuring it suitably. For instance, it would be attractive to define a `log.choose` function as `log.choose <- function(n,k) lgamma(n+1)-lgamma(k+1)-lgamma(n-k+1)` and then invoke it thrice: `myDHyperOverflowFixed <- function(k,K,N,n) log.choose(K,k)+log.choose(N-K,K-k)-log.choose(N,n)`. That kind of programming is more readable, far easier to test and debug, and limits the effects of sly little typographical errors that can plague mathematical code like this.

Answer (score 2):

A side issue:  $n!$ is *equal to* $\Gamma(n+1)$. This is not an approximation but an exact result. The only approximation is arguably in the calculation of $\log\Gamma(n+1)$, but the calculation is quite accurate for positive arguments in the region you're looking at.

Your problem is overflow in `fastChoose`

With such large numbers the value in the denominator of the calculations in `myDHyper` is `Inf` so the results are always 0.

```
> fastChoose(15000,200)
[1] Inf
```

You should instead rewrite `myDHyper` to work entirely on the log scale until the very last step. That should work well enough at these numbers.

(At very large values of the parameters, other strategies may be needed.)

Comment: Hi, I've added another function trying to keep everything on log scale 'for the entire P(X=x) but still this returns large numbers and not probs

Comment: Where does it get exponentiated?

Comment: Hi,there was a copy-paste error i noted above (log should have been lgamma) but that doesn't fix the problem. I exp() when I return the log_p

Comment: Did you try your new code on some simple cases where you can compute log_p by hand? Did you check some cases where your old code worked?

Comment: e.g. compare `log(myDHyper(0,1,3,2))` with the equivalent in your new code.